# Tool to handle the errors in the error log file

Tags: perl, logging, server, internal-server-error

We are developing a script in perl which when gives the url and the webserver to hit. It hits the url given in the webserver and gives the html content of the page.

For example :

```
perl scribehtml.pl --server servername --port portnumber --url /home/firstpage/index.php
```

This returns the entire html code of the page.

Now we are grepping the errors from the html code and write in a text file. Say when we see a text like 'Internal server error' we will put the entire html code into the text file.

There by we are going to have a error.txt where all the errors for different urls will be stored when we execute the script.

Now my Questions are :

1. How to make the error.txt into some log file say error.log and what are things i need to do to make a proper structure log file.
2. Is there any tool in which if we specify the log file it will parse the error in it and display the count of occurrence of each error in the log file in the dashboard.

As for us now I m storing the list of around 500 urls in a text file and parsing the it one by one and executing so there by i am getting error for the urls which are failing and I m writing those errors in the text file error.txt

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to build is a monitoring tool. If you talk about a log file, it sounds like each call produces one line of log, but that is add odds with the rest of what you say. If you want to log and count, consider using a database instead of a flat text file. Sqlite comes to mind here. We also don't know what kind of _dashboard_ you are talking about. As it stands, your question is off-topic on SO because it's too broad and asks for a software recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you can make your own subroutine to store the logs in to the .log file.
The default structure for the log file is as following:

[Timestamp]:Error/Warning/Info: String to define the issue

You can format the lines using printf.